# Como carregar uma imagem dinamicamente no navbar em laravel?

Tags: laravel, image

Ola, ao adicionar um usuário no sistema já estou carregando a foto dele no banco de dados e está sendo armazenada em  storage/app/public/employees/nomedinamicoarquivo.extensao, preciso que essa imagem apareça no navbar quando o usuário logar no sistema.
Dentro do navbar estou passando o caminho do diretório onde a imagem está sendo armazenada e o usuário Auth::user()->name, o objetivo é obter a imagem dinamicamente de acordo como usuário que está logado.

Aqui está a implementação no controller da imagem sendo armazenada.

```
$nameFile = null;

// Verifica se informou o arquivo e se é válido
if ($request->hasFile('imagem') && $request->file('imagem')->isValid()) {

    // Define um aleatório para o arquivo baseado no timestamps atual
    $name = uniqid(date('HisYmd'));
    dd($name);

    // Recupera a extensão do arquivo
    $extension = $request->imagem->extension();

    // Define finalmente o nome
    $nameFile = "{$name}.{$extension}";
    //Faz o upload:
    $upload = $request->imagem->storeAs('employees', $nameFile);
    $request->request->add(['image' => $nameFile]);
    // Se tiver funcionado o arquivo foi armazenado em storage/app/public/employees/nomedinamicoarquivo.extensao
    // Verifica se NÃO deu certo o upload (Redireciona de volta)
    if (!$upload)
        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->with('error', 'Falha ao fazer upload')
            ->withInput();
```

esta é a pasta do projeto onde está sendo armazenado a imagem após cadastrar usuário.

[image]

Aqui está a parte do navbar onde apontamos para a imagem para mostrar na tela do usuário.

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
       <img class="rounded-circle" src="{!! asset('storage/app/public/employees/' . Auth::user()->image) !!}" alt="User" >
  </a>
```

Quando carrego o sistema ele não encontra a imagem, qual a maneira mais correta de chamar essa imagem direto do navbar ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma mutator para esse atributo específico do User, assim o Laravel vai sempre modificar o get() desse atributo e setar um novo valor exemplo:

Se está salvando o nome da imagem no banco e pelo visto usando o storage filesystem de "employees" sua mutator na classe do usuário deverá ser assim:

```
public function getImageAttribute($value)
{
    if (!is_null($value))
        return Storage::disk('employees')->url($value);
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Assim quando usar a função de `auth()->user()->image` sua imagem terá o caminho da storage com a imagem.

para mais informações veja esse link da documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators